# Kunen's Set Theory page 48 Theorem 1.3

Tags: set-theory

from Kunen's Set Theory page 48 Theorem 1.3:

> 1.3.Theorem. If $\kappa \geq \omega$ and $2^{\lt \kappa} = \kappa$, then there is an a.d. family ${\cal A} \subseteq {\cal P}(\kappa)$ with $|{\cal A}| = 2^\kappa$.
> PROOF. Let $I = \left( x \subseteq \kappa : \text{sup}(x) \lt \kappa \right)$. Since $2^{\lt \kappa} = \kappa$, $|I| = \kappa$. $\cdots$

I don't understand why $|I| = \kappa$.

Comment: It is explained *exactly* before it is stated that $|I|=\kappa$.

Comment: $ 2^{\lt \kappa} := \sup_{\alpha< \kappa} 2^\alpha=|I|.$

Comment: why? let me know a bijection: $I \rightarrow 2^{\lt \kappa}$.

Comment: The characteristic functions of the elements of $I$ are exactly the elements of $2^{ \lt \kappa}$.

Comment: how can I prove char:$x \mapsto$ char$(x)$ is bijection?
char$(x)^{-1}(1) = \{ \alpha \in \cup x : \alpha \in x \} = (\cup x) \cap x$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic functions of the elements of $I$ are exactly the elements of $2^{ \lt \kappa}$, so $x \mapsto \operatorname{char}(x)$ is a bijection from $I$ to $2^{\lt \kappa}$.

Comment: how can I prove char$: x \mapsto$ char($x$) is bijection? char($x$)$^{-1}(1) = \{ \alpha \in \cup x : \alpha \in x \} = (\cup x) \cap x$